# Android сжатие изоброжения

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Здраствуйте. У меня есть изоброжения  в обьекте File. Как можно сжать и уменьшить обьем файла а так же узнать его размер?

Comment: Размер файла, в байтах: `long size = file.length();`. А насчёт сжатия нужно уточнить: что имеем и что хотим получить. Большинство форматов изображений и так сжатые, поэтому сжатие без потери качества малоэффективно. Больший эффект даёт уменьшение размера (в пикселах), но  теряется качество.

Comment: @woesss Здравствуйте. Имеем обьект File в котором изоброжения из галереи. Нужно получить уменьшенный в размерах File для отправки на сервер. Сначала думал Получить Bitmap а потом его превратить в File. Но не нашел способа для этого. Мне этот файл нужно после сунуть в okhttp3.RequestBody и с помощью retrofit2 отправить на сервер. Буду рад услышать альтернативы

Comment: Попробую спросить по-другому: Зачем его нужно сжимать? У сервера ограничения какие-то? Или в целях экономии траффика? Можно раскодировать с помощью класса [`BitmapFactory`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.htm) (здесь немножко про загрузку в память уменьшенной копии: [Load a Scaled Down Version into Memory](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap#load-bitmap)), сделать какие-либо преобразования  и сжать уже знакомым Вам `Bitmap.compress()`

Comment: @woesss в целях экономии трафика и ресурсов сервера. Допустим я раскодировал битмап сжал и в конце я остаюсь с файлом битмап который нельзя отправить с помощью ретрофит. Для ретрофит нужно изоброжения в обьекте File.

Comment: Что Вы называете _файлом битмап который нельзя отправить с помощью ретрофит_ ?

Comment: @woesss  Bitmap bm = ...

Comment: Ну так Вы упоминали `Bitmap.compress(...)` - я думал Вы умеете его использовать. Открываете поток в файл, вызываете `compress` с этим потоком, потом отдаёте записанный файл ретрофиту.

Comment: @woesss смутно понял конечно. Маленький пример если не сложно и я всю жизнь буду вам должен

Comment: Можете подсмотреть здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45832835

Answer (score 1):

Сжимать файлы можно элементарно просто архивируя их. Java предоставляет функциональность для работы с таким видом файлов как ZIP-архивы: [статья.](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/6.12.php)

Узнать размер файла можно [таким образом.](https://javatalks.ru/topics/3653)

Comment: Здравствуйте. Не думаю что это подойдет. Мне просто нужно уменьшить размер файла для будущей отправки на сервер. Вы предлогаете отправить зип? Мне нужно что то типа Bitmap.compress() только для файла либо способ получить из битмап файл

Comment: @user8978194, честно говоря, я не думаю, что есть какой-то определённый способ хорошенько сжимать изображение без потерь. Для обычных текстовых, бинарных файлов - аналогично. В таких случаях обычно помогает ZIP-архивация - даёт, может, 5% сжатия, не больше. Если Вас устраивает потеря качества изображения, то преобразуйте его в формат WEBP, он как раз поддерживается устройствами Android.

Comment: WebP это уже интересно. Есть ли библиотеки для андроид?

Comment: @user8978194, https://www.google.ru/search?q=webp+android+library&oq=android+webp+li&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j69i60j0l2.5708j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @user8978194, первые 4 результата поиска должны быть полезны.